# How to access a site via a headless driver without being denied permission

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to retrieve the html code of a site using a headless chrome driver. However I get a "permission denied" message. If I use a "regular" driver it all works fine.

Is there any way to bypass that?

It's my first post so I do apologize for any potential mistakes in formatting

```
from selenium import webdriver

#Headless driver 

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')                                             

driver1 = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver', options=chrome_options, 
service_args=['--verbose', '--log-path=/tmp/chromedriver.log'])

driver1.get('https://www.size.co.uk/')
html = driver1.page_source
html
```

The message I get is:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>\n<title>Access Denied</title>\n</head><body>\n<h1>Access Denied</h1>\n \nYou don\'t have permission to access "http://www.size.co.uk/" on this server.<p>\nReference #18.ac81655f.1548818550.73b12da\n\n\n</p></body></html>
```

Regular driver:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
driver.get('https://www.size.co.uk/')
html = driver.page_source
driver.quit()
html
```

Ideally, I'd like the output to be as in the latter case without having new windows popping up every couple seconds.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Adding in the following code snippet got the page to return for me:

```
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.50 Safari/537.36'    
chrome_options.add_argument('user-agent={0}'.format(user_agent))
```

The site is obviously checking for headless browsers and then denying them access. Here's an article on avoiding detection: [Making Chrome Headless Undetectable](https://intoli.com/blog/making-chrome-headless-undetectable/)

To get the user agent being used by the driver you can run the following command:

```
driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent")
```

Chromes headless user agent is something like this:

> u'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36'

Answer (score 0):

you have to change **user-agent** in code

If you send a lot of requests, you have to change the **user-agent value**  in every request
There are many libraries in Python and other languages ​​to help you How to do it
See link below for how to use it :

[Way to change Google Chrome user agent in Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49565042/way-to-change-google-chrome-user-agent-in-selenium)

Answer (score 0):

This user agent is not working anymore in Heroku:
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/**60.0.3112.50** Safari/537.36'

Using this one works:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me in March 2024:

```
options.addArguments("--headless=new");
```

instead of:

```
options.addArguments("--headless");
```

Try this in combination with the user-agent change suggested by @cullzie