# Google drive API - download public files

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I try to download files from google drive on server (via python).
For small numbers of file it is OK, but when I download more files, I get "permission deny: ("*Sorry, but your computer or network may be sending automated queries, ...*".  OK, OK, understand. ). Python code (with ban from google) is based on this snippet:
https://github.com/ndrplz/google-drive-downloader/blob/master/google_drive_downloader/google_drive_downloader.py

When I switch to Drive API (and create app with permission, scope, ...) I must request scope with read access to client's drive. But I can't do it. I only need download public file, I don't need read all others files. I can't make client scared.

Is it here some solution: *I will make login to my google account and google drive allow to me download public file without ban, limitation, ...?*

Thanks for any idea.

Comment: please edit your question and include your code.

Comment: question has been updated

Comment: Please edit your question and include a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59823253/1841839

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to download public a file with a more restricted scope. It needs at least the `drive.readonly` scope. This of course means your App would have read permissions for the entire Drive. Meanwhile, [drive.file](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/about-auth#OAuth2Authorizing) is limited to files created/opened by your App:

> (drive.file): Per-file access to files created or opened by the app. File authorization is granted on a per-user basis and is revoked when the user deauthorizes the app.

There is a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/168687448) in Google's Issue Tracker asking for this behavior to change. You can click on the star next to the issue number to give more priority to the request and to receive updates.

---

However, a **workaround** would be using an [API Key](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158862?hl=en) instead of Oauth authentication.

Comment: TBH i'm surprised OP is able to do it without an API key to begin with.