# Headless chrome cannot detect elements(selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

It works well when done in non-headless mode but in headless mode no elements are detected.

## code

url: https://moneyforward.com/users/sign_in

I wanna type into mail_address and password and click button in headless mode.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import chromedriver_binary

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get("https://moneyforward.com/users/sign_in")

time.sleep(5)


# type into mail_address
driver.find_element_by_id('sign_in_session_service_email').send_keys({mail_address}])

# type into passowrd
driver.find_element_by_id('sign_in_session_service_password').send_keys({password})

# click login button
driver.find_element_by_id("login-btn-sumit").click()
```

The error statement is as follows.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="sign_in_session_service_email"]"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=80.0.3987.132)
```

Why doesn't it work in headless mode when it works in non-headless mode? Help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took your code and modified a bit and executed at my end and here is the execution result:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  options.headless = True
  options.add_argument('window-size=1400,600')
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://moneyforward.com/users/sign_in')
  print(driver.page_source)
  driver.save_screenshot('./save_screenshot_method.png') #Capture the screen
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  <html><head></head><body><pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">Forbidden</pre></body></html>
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: save_screenshot_method.png]

---

### Analysis

It seems [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) driven [google-chrome-headless](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-headless) is getting detected and being [Access Denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59323836/access-denied-page-with-headless-chrome-on-linux-while-headed-chrome-works-on-wi/59331061#59331061) the message **Forbidden** is shown.

---

### Solution

As a solution you can adopt some strategies so *ChromeDriver* driven *Chrome Browsing context* doesn't gets detected and you can find a couple of detailed discussions in:

- [Selenium webdriver: Modifying navigator.webdriver flag to prevent selenium detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53039551/selenium-webdriver-modifying-navigator-webdriver-flag-to-prevent-selenium-detec/53040904#53040904)
- [Selenium “selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException” when using Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294)

Answer (score 0):

Try to wait for the element rather than just using a hard coded sleep:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC    

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "sign_in_session_service_email"))
```

Before you try that you could crank up the sleep to a higher wait, jsut to debug.

It's also possible that in headless mode your "screen size" isn't configured correctly and is causing a responsive reaction to the screen causing the elements to change.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the page you are accessing does not allow headless browser mode. Try printing the HTML page and see if it returns all elements. I tried by adding the following statement and looks like the application returns the forbidden page.

> print(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*').get_attribute("innerHTML"))

I got this from the URL you have shared.

> Forbidden

You can refer to [Chrome headless options](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) for debugging