# Unable to locate element when using python selenium webdriver chrome on Linux Ubuntu

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Using python, I am trying to get the number in front of the "Advances -" text on the url:
https://www.nseindia.com/market-data/pre-open-market-cm-and-emerge-market

I am using the below xpath:

//*[@id="livepreOpenAdv"]

but getting the below error:

no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="livepreOpenAdv"]"}
(Session info: headless chrome=83.0.4103.61)

I am using chromedriver in Linux (ubuntu 20.04)

Below is the python code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

strURL="https://www.nseindia.com/market-data/pre-open-market-cm-and-emerge-market"

options = Options()

options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver",options=options)

driver.implicitly_wait(60)
driver.get(strURL)

print("Finding element.")

try:
    # advances = driver.find_element_by_id("livepreOpenAdv")
    advances = driver.find_element_by_xpath('''//*[@id="livepreOpenAdv"]''').text
    print(advances)
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)

driver.close()

print("closed driver")
```

This code works fine in windows. Not able to make out what is the issue here.

Comment: You need to use `WebDriverWait`. I was able to get 39 sometimes and sometimes I don't get it. This starting point can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

and replace the line starting with `advances = driver...` with :

```
advances = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@id='livepreOpenAdv']"))).getText()
```

Comment: Getting Timeout exception error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t.py", line 33, in <module>
    advances = WebDriverWait(driver,60).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@id='livepreOpenAdv']")))
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: Remove the `disable-gpu` option (not required on Linux system) and pass the `no-sandbox` as first argument. Remove also the `driver.implicitly_wait(60)` from your script. Also, be sure to check your Chromedriver version and Chrome browser are compatible.

Comment: The chrome browser was not installed in my linux system. I got the chrome installed and with it the chromedriver also got installed. Now both are of same version but still facing the same issue.

Comment: I tried to print driver.title and it gives me "Access Denied". Trying to find a workaround with that but no luck yet. Other urls like www.blgger.com is working fine.

Comment: Then you should check : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54433282/9978746

Answer (score 0):

Finally the below code is working for me. I had to install google-chrome-stable package through apt. Also suggestions from @E.Wiest helped. Thanks!
As this was an headless execution, the url was giving access denied message. Added user-agent parameter to resolve that.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

strURL="https://www.nseindia.com/market-data/pre-open-market-cm-and-emerge-market"

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument(f'user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36')

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver",options=options)

t1=time.time()
driver.get(strURL)

strXpath_advances='//*[@id="livepreOpenAdv"]'
strXpath_decline='//*[@id="livepreOpenDec"]'

try:
    advances = WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, strXpath_advances)))
    decline = WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, strXpath_decline)))
    print("Advances={} Decline={}".format(advances.text,decline.text))
except Exception as ex:
    print("Exception=",ex)

t2=time.time()-t1
driver.close()
print("Done. closed driver. Time={0:.2f}".format(t2))
```